# Instrumenting DataDog on aws Lambda, cannot not find my function

Tags: typescript, docker, lambda, aws-lambda, datadog

I am having problems doing a Datadog [Instrumenting](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/nodejs/?tab=containerimage) in a Typescript Lambda function

this is my folder structure:

[image]

and this is how looks my docker file:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16

COPY --from=public.ecr.aws/datadog/lambda-extension:latest /opt/extensions/ /opt/extensions

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/build ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/package.json ./

RUN mkdir -p ./output
RUN npm install --omit=dev

ENV DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER ="app.handler"

RUN rm node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.js
CMD ["node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/handler.handler"]
```

also, these are my dependencies on the package.json

[image]

and well all the docker build and deploy works well, but at the moment I try to invoke my function I received an error related to not finding my `app.handler` function.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module '=app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/index.js","trace":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '=app'","Require stack:","- /var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js","- /var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/index.js","    at ImportModuleError.ExtendedError [as constructor] (/var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/errors.js:113:28)","    at new ImportModuleError (/var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/errors.js:123:42)","    at /var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js:273:31","    at step (/var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js:43:23)","    at Object.throw (/var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js:24:53)","    at rejected (/var/task/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/dist/runtime/user-function.js:16:65)"]}%
```

Of course when I change my CMD in the docker file for:

```
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

everything works perfectly

any idea about what am I missing in the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

well, I made it work using this implementation option:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/guide/handler_wrapper/

basically was wrap the handler function with datadog, and keep using my app.handler as my entry point in the Dockerfile

```
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

here is how looks my app.ts file:

[image]